# PowerPoint Show Slide (or Thumbnail) Pane from Left to Right

Tags: powerpoint

Due to some Development work, I have set my monitors in vertical orientation (portrait mode). I am trying to use PowerPoint and since the Slide Pane (Thumbnail pane) is usually located on the left side of the slide, due to my current orientation, it takes some large amount of real estate.

Is it possible for the Slide (or thumbnail) pane to show up on Left to Right in PowerPoint?

Below schematic describes what I am asking for.

[image]

Thanks.